# General Protection error when using NI VISION imaqDetectLines() function

Tags: c, image-processing, labwindows, cvi

I am using National Instruments Vision module in Labwindows\CVI

For some reason, when i use the func `imaqDetectLines()`, i get `FATAL RUN-TIME ERROR:   "Angle tracker.c", line 50, col 11, thread id 0x00002004:   The program has caused a 'General Protection' fault at 0x6C5AD446.`

This is my code:

```
#include "nivision.h"
#include <userint.h>
#include <cvirte.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nLines;
    ShapeDetectionOptions stShapeDetectionOption;
    RangeFloat aAngleRanges[2]={{0,10.0},{10.0,20.0}};
    CurveOptions stCurveOptions = {0};
    LineMatch *aLm;
    LineDescriptor lineDesc;
    Image *imageHdl = NULL, *imageDestHdl = NULL;
    char temp[1024] ="";

    if (InitCVIRTE (0, argv, 0) == 0)
        return -1;    /* out of memory */

    imageHdl = imaqCreateImage (0/*U8*/,1); 
    imageDestHdl = imaqCreateImage (0/*U8*/,1); 

    strcpy(temp,"C:\\CVI2013\\Projects\\Angel Tracker\\IMG\\CC01.bmp");

    imaqReadFile (imageHdl, temp, NULL, NULL);

    imaqEdgeFilter (imageDestHdl, imageHdl, IMAQ_EDGE_SOBEL, NULL);

    lineDesc.maxLength = 100;
    lineDesc.minLength = 50;

    stShapeDetectionOption.minMatchScore = 1;
    stShapeDetectionOption.mode = 0;
    stShapeDetectionOption.numAngleRanges = 1;
    stShapeDetectionOption.angleRanges = aAngleRanges;
    stShapeDetectionOption.scaleRange.minValue = 1;
    stShapeDetectionOption.scaleRange.maxValue = 10;

    stCurveOptions.extractionMode = 0;
    stCurveOptions.threshold = 100;
    stCurveOptions.filterSize = 1;
    stCurveOptions.minLength = 100;
    stCurveOptions.rowStepSize = 10;
    stCurveOptions.columnStepSize = 10;
    stCurveOptions.maxEndPointGap = 1000;
    stCurveOptions.onlyClosed = TRUE;
    stCurveOptions.subpixelAccuracy = TRUE;

    aLm = imaqDetectLines(imageDestHdl, &lineDesc, &stCurveOptions
                           ,&stShapeDetectionOption, NULL, &nLines);

    return 0;
}
```

what i am actually doing is:

1. Open a BMP file
2. Edge filltering it with `imaqEdgeFilter()` func using SOBEL
3. Then i want to detect lines with `imaqDetectLines()` func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

if you look at the function call:

```
aLm = imaqDetectLines(imageDestHdl, &lineDesc, &stCurveOptions
                       ,&stShapeDetectionOption, NULL, &nLines);
```

For the ROI parameter i passed NULL because i got this from The function panel help:

> The region of interest applied to the image that specifies where circles can be detected. Set this parameter to NULL to search the entire image.

But, apparently it is a known bug and it will be fixed, so in order to workaround this, just do the following:

```
ROI *roi;    
imaqSetWindowROI (0, NULL);    
roi = imaqGetWindowROI (0);
```

And then send it to the function:

```
aLm = imaqDetectLines(imageDestHdl, &lineDesc, &stCurveOptions
                       ,&stShapeDetectionOption, roi, &nLines);
```